# Is asking about grad school off topic for Chemistry.SE?

Tags: discussion

I'm a 3rd year undergraduate student studying chemistry, and I'm starting to think about grad school. I've enjoyed the different chem courses I've taken, so it's hard for me to pick a subcategory of chemistry to study.

Are there books or other resources available which describe in depth how the rubber meets the road for the different fields of chemistry? I've spoken with my professors somewhat and I plan to continue doing so, but I would like a text-based resource which I could refer to and look up or research the words and concepts contained in it.

Comment: Asking about this stuff is off topic for this site, but feel free to discuss in [chat] or perhaps try [academia.se] :)

Comment: +1 for [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).  That community is amazing.